# Translating a View outside the bounds of screen and animating it back

Tags: java, android, eclipse, animation

I am using following code, I have a Relative Layout of height 50dp, I want it to animate it  and move above the screen. This animation works fine.

However when i bring it back, it jerks.

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -100);
        anim.setDuration(1000);

        anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
            {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationView.getLayoutParams();
                params.topMargin   -= 100;
                locationView.setLayoutParams(params);
                locationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });



Bringing back code


TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, +100);
        anim.setDuration(1000);

        anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) 
            {       
                locationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
            {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationView.getLayoutParams();
                params.topMargin   += 100;
                locationView.setLayoutParams(params);               
            }
        });
        locationView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have expected something different

This translate the top of your view from `0` to `-100px`

```
 TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -100);
```

and `onAnimationEnd` just change its visibility to `GONE`, without change its layout params. To bring it back, you have to translate the top of your view from `-100px` to `0`

```
 TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -100, 0);
```

before HoneyComb, if the view is not visible, the animation will not start, and onAnimationStart will not be fired, so you should call

```
locationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

before `view.startAnimation(anim);`